# Cfn Cluster fails at creating master server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to create cfncluster by issuing the command "pip install cfncluster"and cluster creaton fails when creating the master server it says resource creation failed. Please find the logs below. kindly help me resolve the issue.

```
2016-06-04  Status  Type    Logical ID  Status reason
00:50:08 UTC+0550   ROLLBACK_COMPLETE   AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  cfncluster-cfnclustertest   
00:47:35 UTC+0550   ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  cfncluster-cfnclustertest   The following resource(s) failed to create: MasterServer. . Rollback requested by user.
00:47:34 UTC+0550   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::EC2::Instance  MasterServer    Failed to receive 1 resource signal(s) within the specified duration
Physical ID:i-ea2af076
00:16:26 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::Instance  MasterServer    Resource creation Initiated
Physical ID:i-ea2af076
00:16:24 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::Instance  MasterServer    
00:16:16 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile   RootInstanceProfile 
00:14:21 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation    AssosiateEIP    
00:14:15 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile   RootInstanceProfile Resource creation Initiated
00:14:15 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile   RootInstanceProfile 
00:14:14 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::IAM::Policy    CfnClusterPolicies  
00:14:14 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::Policy    CfnClusterPolicies  Resource creation Initiated
00:14:13 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::Policy    CfnClusterPolicies  
00:14:06 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::IAM::Role  RootRole    
00:14:05 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation    AssosiateEIP    Resource creation Initiated
00:14:04 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  ComputeSecurityGroupIngress 
00:14:04 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  MasterSecurityGroupIngress  
00:14:03 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation    AssosiateEIP    
00:14:03 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  MasterSecurityGroupIngress  Resource creation Initiated
00:14:03 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  ComputeSecurityGroupIngress Resource creation Initiated
00:14:02 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  MasterSecurityGroupIngress  
00:14:02 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  ComputeSecurityGroupIngress 
00:13:55 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface  MasterENI   
00:13:55 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup ComputeSecurityGroup    
00:13:53 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup ComputeSecurityGroup    Resource creation Initiated
00:13:39 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface  MasterENI   Resource creation Initiated
00:13:37 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface  MasterENI   
00:13:37 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup ComputeSecurityGroup    
00:13:31 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::Role  RootRole    Resource creation Initiated
00:13:31 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup MasterSecurityGroup 
00:13:29 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup MasterSecurityGroup Resource creation Initiated
00:13:24 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::DynamoDB::Table    DynamoDBTable   
00:13:19 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy   SQSPolicy   
00:13:19 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy   SQSPolicy   Resource creation Initiated
00:13:18 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy   SQSPolicy   
00:13:13 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup MasterSecurityGroup 
00:13:13 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::SNS::Topic SNS 
00:13:11 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::EC2::Volume    SharedVolume    
00:13:09 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::EC2::EIP   MasterEIP   
00:13:01 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::SNS::Topic SNS Resource creation Initiated
00:13:00 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::SNS::Topic SNS 
00:12:55 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::IAM::Role  RootRole    
00:12:55 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::Volume    SharedVolume    Resource creation Initiated
00:12:54 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::Volume    SharedVolume    
00:12:53 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::DynamoDB::Table    DynamoDBTable   Resource creation Initiated
00:12:53 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::EIP   MasterEIP   Resource creation Initiated
00:12:53 UTC+0550   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::SQS::Queue SQS 
00:12:53 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::DynamoDB::Table    DynamoDBTable   
00:12:53 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::EIP   MasterEIP   
00:12:51 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::SQS::Queue SQS Resource creation Initiated
00:12:50 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::SQS::Queue SQS 
00:12:44 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  cfncluster-cfnclustertest   User Initiated
```

Comment: Paste your CFN code too

Comment: CFN code? i am not sure what exactly you are asking. i am following the steps mentioned in this document. http://cfncluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#installing-cfncluster. if i use a public vpc i am able to create the cluster but when  i use vpc with firewall protected master node is not creating. can you please ellaborate your question.

Comment: With "vpc with firewall protected master node" means what exactly are you doing here ? Can you give the steps?

Comment: i mean i am able to create a cluster using a public vpc. but when i use a vpc which is using custom DNS i am not able to create cfncluster. the cluster creation fails at creation of master node.

Comment: The problem happening here is when the EC2 instance is created in public VPC it has internet connection so it send back the success signal. But when it gets created in Private Subnet it does not have a internet connection so the success signal is not sent back to CFN and hence it thinks it failed and tools back. You have to make sure that EC2 instance has a Internet connection through NAT first.

Comment: when i give the command cfncluster create --norollback mycluster. i could see the master instance being created  and still running  in the EC2 dashboard but in cloudformation stacklist log and  in command line  it says master instance CREATE FAILED. please check below: Stack name:
cfncluster-cfnclustertest
Status:
CREATE_FAILED
Status reason:
The following resource(s) failed to create: [MasterServer].

Comment: Ok for this step Acceptable Values for Master Subnet ID: do you choose Public Subnet or private subnet?

Comment: i am using private subnet.

Comment: When a EC2 instance gets created in Private subnet it does not have internet connection by default you have to provide that using a NAT instance. As the EC2 instance does not have internet it is not able to sent the creation complete signal back to the CFN agent check this error "Failed to receive 1 resource signal(s)" so the EC2 instance is getting created but as the CFN agent does not receive the signal it thinks that there was a issue and it rolls back the changes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. it was very helpful in figuring out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a EC2 instance gets created in Private subnet it does not have internet connection by default you have to provide that using a NAT instance. As the EC2 instance does not have internet it is not able to sent the creation complete signal back to the CFN agent check this error "Failed to receive 1 resource signal(s)" so the EC2 instance is getting created but as the CFN agent does not receive the signal it thinks that there was a issue and it rolls back the changes

Answer (score 0):

Adding the security group that is working for internet access  in the configuration settings of CFNcluster config file I am able to create the cluster successfully.